# How to use MemoryMeasurer in jave web project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, memory

> MemoryMeasurer, which can estimate the memory footprint of an object
>   graph in bytes. This requires installing a javaagent when running the
>   JVM, e.g. by passing -javaagent:path/to/object-explorer.jar.

I am developing a java web project using tomcat, I hope to check some obejct size every one hour, what does the doc  "by passing -javaagent:path/to/object-explorer.jar." mean? What should I do to make it available in my web project both when running with WAR or in eclipse?

When I test this method, I got

```
Instrumentation is not setup properly. You have to pass -javaagent:path/to/object-explorer.jar to the java interpreter
```

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPerformance/article.html

Comment: Take heap dumps every time you want to analyze memory. Feed heap dumps to jvisualvm shipped with jdk, and there you can analyze the application.